# date and time conversions in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

How can I convert 1910-01-01 00:03:01.5 to milliseconds using pyspark library?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'to milliseconds'?

Comment: I am having a csv file containing a column named transaction_date, which is in mm:ss.sss format and it is of string type. I have to find out the sum of transactions happened within last 1 hour.[ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096425/running-sum-of-last-one-hour-transaction-using-spark-scala]. In order to use the query in the given link i have to convert the time into milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

use `unix_timestamp` function to get epoch time.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('1910-01-01 00:03:01.5',)],['ts'])
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.withColumn("ts",unix_timestamp(col("ts"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')).\
show(10,False)
#+-----------+
#|ts         |
#+-----------+
#|-1893427018|
#+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I used unix_timestamp function to calculate the time in milliseconds from 1970-01-01  00:00:00 , I got the output as 19790. But I should get 0 milliseconds, right?

Comment: Can we find the sum of all transactions in last 1hr using pyspark library? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096425/running-sum-of-last-one-hour-transaction-using-spark-scala]